# How can I make Fresnel edges softer?

Tags: shader-nodes

Below is a poorly drawn representation of what Fresnel does to my model: it covers part of it with a hard edge.

[image: Normal Fresnel]

And this is what I want to be able to do; this illustration shows the Fresnel with a softer edge:

[image: Fresnel I want]

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hello, maybe show some pictures of your object, it should not create hard edges, you can also try to put a ColorRamp after the Fresnel, also you could try the Layer Weight, Facing output?

Answer (score 4):

### Index of Refraction < `1.0`

I was able to replicate your problem by putting an *IOR* value less than `1.0` in the *Fresnel Node*

[image]

Try bringing in a new *Fresnel Node* and it should come in with an *IOR* of `1.450`

[image]